# Forum software - Stores all images in database

Tags: forum, user-forums

I am looking for PHP based forum software that will store **all uploaded** images into the database and not the file system.

I'm busy going through this list http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Internet_forum_software_%28PHP%29, but I'm hoping someone here knows of something already.

Disclaimer: Yes, I am fully aware storing images in a database is silly but this is a "must be met" requirement by the client.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

After going through all the forum systems, this is nigh impossible unless you rewrite parts of the system.